# How can I jump to another page by clicking a button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to redirect my page by clicking a button. But I am totally messed up by the quotes.

Here is the code:

```
child.innerHTML += "<a class='sliding-element' href='javascript:sendSurvey(" + (m + 1) + ")'>Survey " + surveyList[m].Name + "</a>" + "<input type='button' onClick='parent.location='QuestionPage.aspx''/>";
```

It can't redirect me to the QuestionPage.aspx. It simply does nothing.

Comment: why can't you just use a standard link and style it as a button? Or if you are dying to use the browser input buttons, just wrap that in a standard link?

Comment: And what does the generated HTML link look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your function does, but you could try escaping the double quotes:

```
child.innerHTML += "<a class=\"sliding-element\" href=\"javascript:sendSurvey(\" + (m + 1) + \")\">Survey " + surveyList[m].Name + "</a>" + "<input type=\"button\" onClick="parent.location=\"QuestionPage.aspx\""/>";
```

Comment: Yes, because their answers were incorrect. That's what downvoting means. And now the accepted answer has a glaring syntax error, that even the Markdown syntax highlighting makes obvious.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I reserve downvotes for misleading answers, not for small mistakes, I that case, I'd rather just make a comment.

Comment: @Juan: The question is "please fix my quotes". This answer makes them worse. It's hardly a small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Don't construct the HTML, construct the elements:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.className = "sliding-element";
link.href = "";
link.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    sendSurvey(m + 1);
};
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Survey " + surveyList[m].Name));
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type = "button";
btn.value = "click me";
btn.onclick = function (e) {
    parent.location.href = "QuestionPage.aspx";
};
child.appendChild(link);
child.appendChild(btn);
```

It's a little more verbose, but less prone to errors.

Comment: `document.createElement("<input type=button>")` [Are you sure that will work?](http://jsfiddle.net/uUtw2/) Also, why `e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: The [documentation on createElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(VS.85).aspx) lists that syntax.  I'm not sure if it's still the case with modern browsers, but it at least used to be that you couldn't specify the `type` of an `input` after it had been created, hence the need for the syntax that allows attributes.  The `&&` is shorthand for `if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: You can set the type with `setAttribute()`, I don't think the `type` property works. Also, you're right on the latter, I didn't notice the `()` missing on the LHS :)

Comment: I just tested it out.  The type property works as long as it is set before the element is added to the dom.  That doesn't really explain why I had it in my head that you have to pass the type to `createElement`.  Maybe it was an IE4 issue, but I'm not going to drag out an old 386 PC just to test that theory.  I like the explicit property assignment better - I'll update my answer to do the `appendChild` at the end.

Comment: Did you try it in IE7? That's where I remember the `type` property failing, but maybe it is just my memory that is failing :P

Comment: @gily3: That syntax is for IE, don't use it.

Answer (score -2):

```
child.innerHTML += "<a class='sliding-element' href='javascript:sendSurvey(" + (m + 1) + ")'>Survey " + surveyList[m].Name + "</a>" + "<input type='button' onClick=\"parent.location='QuestionPage.aspx'\"/>";
```

There's a problem with your quotation marks: You need to use escaped " and not nested '

Comment: That's not true. Write `window.location = 'http://www.google.com';` in your Firebug console to see.

Answer (score -2):

Here's your code made legible-ish:

```
child.innerHTML += "<a class='sliding-element'"
                +  "href='javascript:sendSurvey(" + (m + 1) + ")'>Survey "
                +   surveyList[m].Name + "</a>"
                +  "<input type='button' "
                +  "onClick='parent.location='QuestionPage.aspx''/>";
```

The quotes inside `onClick` (that last line) are wrong. You have nested quotes and must escape them, and there's an extra quote at the end.

Change to:

```
child.innerHTML += "<a class='sliding-element'"
                +  "href='javascript:sendSurvey(" + (m + 1) + ")'>Survey "
                +   surveyList[m].Name + "</a>"
                +  "<input type='button' "
                +  "onClick='parent.location=\"QuestionPage.aspx\" />";
```

Comment: Insted of parent.location, shouldn't it be window.location or document.location whichever browser supports, at this point parent object would refer to it's DOM parent.

Comment: @Bipins: Perhaps, not sure. I'm only fixing the quotes, not changing the semantics of his script or reviewing its merits.

Comment: @Juan: You just did it for me!

Comment: @Bipins - See the [documentation on `parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent).  You are probably thinking of `this.parentNode`.